# Rhythmbox will not start

Tags: 14.04, software-center, rhythmbox, music

I have recently uninstalled **Rhythmbox** on my Ubuntu 14.04 laptop, through the **Ubuntu Software Center** and, because it still appeared under the sound icon, I ran the command `sudo apt-get purge rhythmbox` in **Terminal**. In case you are wondering why, Rhythmbox was failing to start on a regular basis, so I foolishly thought that a simple reinstall would make life better!

Next I installed **Rhythmbox** again through the **Ubuntu Software Center** now, when I click the icon to run it, nothing happens and when I enter the command `rhythmbox` in terminal, I receive the following error.

```
$ rhythmbox
rhythmbox: error while loading shared libraries: libtotem-plparser.so.17: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

How do I reinstall the shared libraries libtotem-plparser.so.17 or access/re-create the necessary shared object file?

### I have tried:

the fix on [Missing shared library for Rhythmbox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/368128/missing-shared-library-for-rhythmbox) Changing the **<s>librhythmbox-core7</s>** to **librhythmbox-core8**:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install gir1.2-rb-3.0 librhythmbox-core8 rhythmbox rhythmbox-data rhythmbox-mozilla rhythmbox-plugin-cdrecorder rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist rhythmbox-plugins
```

I also tried the fix on [Rhythmbox does not start after upgrading to Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/449579/rhythmbox-does-not-start-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-14-04)

but still get the same error message in both cases:

```
$ rhythmbox
rhythmbox: error while loading shared libraries: libtotem-plparser.so.17: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

### Update 1

Suggested by [Jobin](https://askubuntu.com/users/72576/jobin)

```
$ ls -l /usr/lib/libtotem-plparser.so.18:
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 27 Apr  1 14:32 /usr/lib/libtotem-plparser.so.18 -> libtotem-plparser.so.18.1.0
```

### Update 2

I have tried downloading and reinstalling rhythmbox 3:

```
simon@simon-TS44HR:~/Downloads/rhythmbox-3.0.2$ ./configure
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking whether UID '1000' is supported by ustar format... yes
checking whether GID '1000' is supported by ustar format... yes
checking how to create a ustar tar archive... gnutar
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... (cached) yes
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for gobject-introspection... yes
checking whether NLS is requested... yes
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking for intltool >= 0.35.0... 0.50.2 found
checking for intltool-update... /usr/bin/intltool-update
checking for intltool-merge... /usr/bin/intltool-merge
checking for intltool-extract... /usr/bin/intltool-extract
checking for xgettext... /usr/bin/xgettext
checking for msgmerge... /usr/bin/msgmerge
checking for msgfmt... /usr/bin/msgfmt
checking for gmsgfmt... /usr/bin/msgfmt
checking for perl... /usr/bin/perl
checking for perl >= 5.8.1... 5.18.2
checking for XML::Parser... ok
checking for library containing strerror... none required
checking for gcc... (cached) gcc
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... (cached) yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... (cached) yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... (cached) none needed
checking dependency style of gcc... (cached) gcc3
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking how to print strings... printf
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for fgrep... /bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by gcc... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1572864
checking whether the shell understands some XSI constructs... yes
checking whether the shell understands "+="... yes
checking how to convert x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu file names to x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu format... func_convert_file_noop
checking how to convert x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu file names to toolchain format... func_convert_file_noop
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for objdump... objdump
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for dlltool... no
checking how to associate runtime and link libraries... printf %s\n
checking for ar... ar
checking for archiver @FILE support... @
checking for strip... strip
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from gcc object... ok
checking for sysroot... no
checking for mt... mt
checking if mt is a manifest tool... no
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for gcc option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if gcc PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if gcc static flag -static works... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the gcc linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... no
configure: creating ./config.lt
config.lt: creating libtool
checking whether byte ordering is bigendian... no
checking size of long... 8
checking for pkg-config... (cached) /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.16... yes
checking for GNU extension fwrite_unlocked... yes
checking for pkg-config... (cached) /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for RB_CLIENT... yes
checking for RHYTHMBOX... yes
checking for TOTEM_PLPARSER... yes
checking for GUDEV... yes
checking for HAL... no
checking for IPOD... yes
checking for MTP... yes
checking for LIBSECRET... yes
checking for GSTREAMER... yes
checking for NOTIFY... yes
Your libnotify version is 0,7,6.
checking for uncompress in -lz... yes
checking for X... libraries , headers 
checking for gethostbyname... yes
checking for connect... yes
checking for remove... yes
checking for shmat... yes
checking for IceConnectionNumber in -lICE... yes
checking for XFree86 headers... yes
checking for LIBBRASERO_MEDIA... yes
checking for glib-genmarshal... /usr/bin/glib-genmarshal
checking for gdk-pixbuf-csource... /usr/bin/gdk-pixbuf-csource
checking whether strftime supports %E and %O modifiers... yes
checking for msgfmt... (cached) /usr/bin/msgfmt
checking for gmsgfmt... (cached) /usr/bin/msgfmt
checking for xgettext... (cached) /usr/bin/xgettext
checking for msgmerge... (cached) /usr/bin/msgmerge
checking for ld used by GCC... /usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) is GNU ld... yes
checking for shared library run path origin... done
checking for CFPreferencesCopyAppValue... no
checking for CFLocaleCopyCurrent... no
checking for GNU gettext in libc... yes
checking whether to use NLS... yes
checking where the gettext function comes from... libc
checking lirc/lirc_client.h usability... yes
checking lirc/lirc_client.h presence... yes
checking for lirc/lirc_client.h... yes
checking for lirc_init in -llirc_client... yes
checking for WEBKIT... yes
checking for more warnings... no
checking whether gcc understands -fno-strict-aliasing... yes
checking for gtk-doc... yes
checking for gtkdoc-check... gtkdoc-check.test
checking for gtkdoc-check... /usr/bin/gtkdoc-check
checking for gtkdoc-rebase... /usr/bin/gtkdoc-rebase
checking for gtkdoc-mkpdf... /usr/bin/gtkdoc-mkpdf
checking whether to build gtk-doc documentation... no
checking for GTKDOC_DEPS... yes
checking for itstool... itstool
checking for xmllint... xmllint
checking for a Python interpreter with version >= 3.2.3... python3
checking for python3... /usr/bin/python3
checking for python3 version... 3.4
checking for python3 platform... linux
checking for python3 script directory... ${prefix}/lib/python3.4/site-packages
checking for python3 extension module directory... ${exec_prefix}/lib/python3.4/site-packages
checking for PYTHON... yes
checking whether Vala plugin support is requested... autodetect
checking whether FM radio support is requested... checking linux/videodev2.h usability... yes
checking linux/videodev2.h presence... yes
checking for linux/videodev2.h... yes
checking for CHECK... no
checking for DMAPSHARING... yes
checking for CLUTTER... yes
checking for GRILO... no
checking that generated files are newer than configure... done
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating rhythmbox.pc
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating lib/Makefile
config.status: creating lib/libmediaplayerid/Makefile
config.status: creating metadata/Makefile
config.status: creating rhythmdb/Makefile
config.status: creating widgets/Makefile
config.status: creating podcast/Makefile
config.status: creating shell/Makefile
config.status: creating data/Makefile
config.status: creating data/rhythmbox.desktop.in
config.status: creating data/rhythmbox-device.desktop.in
config.status: creating data/ui/Makefile
config.status: creating data/icons/Makefile
config.status: creating data/icons/hicolor/Makefile
config.status: creating data/icons/hicolor/16x16/Makefile
config.status: creating data/icons/hicolor/16x16/apps/Makefile
config.status: creating data/icons/hicolor/16x16/status/Makefile
config.status: creating data/icons/hicolor/22x22/Makefile
config.status: creating data/icons/hicolor/22x22/apps/Makefile
config.status: creating data/icons/hicolor/24x24/Makefile
config.status: creating data/icons/hicolor/24x24/apps/Makefile
config.status: creating data/icons/hicolor/32x32/Makefile
config.status: creating data/icons/hicolor/32x32/apps/Makefile
config.status: creating data/icons/hicolor/48x48/Makefile
config.status: creating data/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/Makefile
config.status: creating data/icons/hicolor/48x48/status/Makefile
config.status: creating data/icons/hicolor/256x256/Makefile
config.status: creating data/icons/hicolor/256x256/apps/Makefile
config.status: creating data/icons/hicolor/scalable/Makefile
config.status: creating data/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps/Makefile
config.status: creating data/icons/src/Makefile
config.status: creating sources/Makefile
config.status: creating sources/sync/Makefile
config.status: creating plugins/Makefile
config.status: creating plugins/audiocd/Makefile
config.status: creating plugins/audioscrobbler/Makefile
config.status: creating plugins/brasero-disc-recorder/Makefile
config.status: creating plugins/daap/Makefile
config.status: creating plugins/fmradio/Makefile
config.status: creating plugins/im-status/Makefile
config.status: creating plugins/ipod/Makefile
config.status: creating plugins/mtpdevice/Makefile
config.status: creating plugins/iradio/Makefile
config.status: creating plugins/lirc/Makefile
config.status: creating plugins/lyrics/Makefile
config.status: creating plugins/pythonconsole/Makefile
config.status: creating plugins/artsearch/Makefile
config.status: creating plugins/magnatune/Makefile
config.status: creating plugins/generic-player/Makefile
config.status: creating plugins/rb/Makefile
config.status: creating plugins/rb/rbconfig.py
config.status: creating plugins/power-manager/Makefile
config.status: creating plugins/mmkeys/Makefile
config.status: creating plugins/context/Makefile
config.status: creating plugins/sendto/Makefile
config.status: creating plugins/replaygain/Makefile
config.status: creating plugins/mpris/Makefile
config.status: creating plugins/dbus-media-server/Makefile
config.status: creating plugins/rbzeitgeist/Makefile
config.status: creating plugins/notification/Makefile
config.status: creating plugins/visualizer/Makefile
config.status: creating plugins/grilo/Makefile
config.status: creating sample-plugins/Makefile
config.status: creating sample-plugins/sample/Makefile
config.status: creating sample-plugins/sample-python/Makefile
config.status: creating sample-plugins/sample-vala/Makefile
config.status: creating bindings/Makefile
config.status: creating bindings/vala/Makefile
config.status: creating bindings/gi/Makefile
config.status: creating help/Makefile
config.status: creating po/Makefile.in
config.status: creating tests/Makefile
config.status: creating doc/Makefile
config.status: creating doc/reference/Makefile
config.status: creating backends/Makefile
config.status: creating backends/gstreamer/Makefile
config.status: creating remote/Makefile
config.status: creating remote/dbus/Makefile
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: executing depfiles commands
config.status: executing libtool commands
config.status: executing po-directories commands
config.status: creating po/POTFILES
config.status: creating po/Makefile
config.status: executing po/stamp-it commands
configure: Rhythmbox was configured with the following options:
configure: ** Tree database is enabled
configure: ** Multimedia keys support is enabled
configure: ** iPod integration enabled
configure: ** MTP integration enabled
configure: ** CD burning support enabled
configure: ** DAAP (music sharing) support is enabled
configure: ** libnotify support is enabled
configure: ** WebKit support is enabled
configure: ** GUdev support enabled
configure: ** Python plugin support enabled
configure:    Vala plugin support disabled
configure: ** Libsecret keyring support enabled
configure: ** FM radio support enabled
configure: ** iTunes detection browser plugin (for podcasts) enabled
configure: ** Visualizer plugin enabled
configure: End options
```

When I make the file it runs well until:

```
  File "/usr/lib/gobject-introspection/giscanner/cachestore.py", line 148, in _clean
    self._remove_filename(os.path.join(self._directory, filename))
  File "/usr/lib/gobject-introspection/giscanner/cachestore.py", line 130, in _remove_filename
    os.unlink(filename)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/simon/.cache/g-ir-scanner/c3fdfb2eef221c4c5ec8d16026d3ec132ad90e39'
make[3]: *** [MPID-3.0.gir] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/simon/Downloads/rhythmbox-3.0.2/bindings/gi'
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/simon/Downloads/rhythmbox-3.0.2/bindings'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/simon/Downloads/rhythmbox-3.0.2'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Then running Rhythmbox from the Terminal gives:

```
simon@simon-TS44HR:~/Downloads/rhythmbox-3.0.2$ rhythmbox
rhythmbox: error while loading shared libraries: libtotem-plparser.so.17: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'
```

### Update 3 from [Dobey](https://askubuntu.com/users/50737/dobey)

```
$ apt-cache policy rhythmbox
rhythmbox:
  Installed: 3.0.2-0ubuntu2
  Candidate: 3.0.2-0ubuntu2
  Version table:
 *** 3.0.2-0ubuntu2 0
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     3.0.2-0ubuntu1 0
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

### Update 4 by [sneetsher](https://askubuntu.com/users/26246/sneetsher)

After running `sudo dpkg -i libtotem-plparser17_3.4.5-1_amd64.deb` in terminal

```
$ rhythmbox

(rhythmbox:4104): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_settings_new_with_path: assertion 'path_is_valid (path)' failed

(rhythmbox:4104): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_settings_new_with_path: assertion 'path_is_valid (path)' failed

(rhythmbox:4104): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance

(rhythmbox:4104): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_object: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed

(rhythmbox:4104): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_settings_get_value: assertion 'G_IS_SETTINGS (settings)' failed

(rhythmbox:4104): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_variant_get_type: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

(rhythmbox:4104): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_variant_type_is_subtype_of: assertion 'g_variant_type_check (type)' failed

(rhythmbox:4104): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_variant_get_boolean: assertion 'g_variant_is_of_type (value, G_VARIANT_TYPE_BOOLEAN)' failed

(rhythmbox:4104): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_variant_unref: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

(rhythmbox:4104): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance

(rhythmbox:4104): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_object: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed

(rhythmbox:4104): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_settings_get_value: assertion 'G_IS_SETTINGS (settings)' failed

(rhythmbox:4104): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_variant_get_type: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

(rhythmbox:4104): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_variant_type_is_subtype_of: assertion 'g_variant_type_check (type)' failed

(rhythmbox:4104): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_variant_get_boolean: assertion 'g_variant_is_of_type (value, G_VARIANT_TYPE_BOOLEAN)' failed

(rhythmbox:4104): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_variant_unref: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

(rhythmbox:4104): Rhythmbox-WARNING **: Could not open device /dev/radio0
```

Comment: @fossfreedom when I originally upgraded to 14.04, I found that the latest version of rhythmbox, from https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Rhythmbox failed to run. I have purged and reinstalled it numerous times to try and get it working! I see that you have written a plug-in equaliser which I will install when I get it all working OK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Well, `libtotem-plparser17` is not available in Trusty repo:

  http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libtotem-plparser17&searchon=names

  In my Ubuntu 14.04, I've both `libtotem-plparser17` and `libtotem-plparser18`, most probably because I made an upgrade from Saucy.
- So suggest downloading & installing Saucy `libtotem-plparser17` pacakge, from:

  http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/libtotem-plparser17

  64bit package:

  ```
  wget http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/t/totem-pl-parser/libtotem-plparser17_3.4.5-1_amd64.deb
  sudo dpkg -i libtotem-plparser17_3.4.5-1_amd64.deb
  ```

  32bit package:

  ```
  wget http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/t/totem-pl-parser/libtotem-plparser17_3.4.5-1_i386.deb
  sudo dpkg -i libtotem-plparser17_3.4.5-1_i386.deb
  ```

  I'm not sure about any of its dependencies.
- Even if it works, that was just a workaround. Possibly, you've multiple copies of Rhythmbox executable.

  1. Check `which rhythmbox` (@fossfreedom asked about already) or try run `/usr/bin/rhythmbox`
  2. Check `sudo updatedb; locate -r /bin/rhythmbox$` (this should cover regular installation `configure`, executable in a bin/ folder )
- **If you get multiple copies**, clean up manually installed Rhythmbox

  1. Check if all list files/folders are related rhythmbox (As `rm -rf` is dangerous command)

     ```
     find /usr/local/ -iname *rhythmbox* -exec rm -rf {} \;
     ```
  2. If it's ok, add `sudo` to it:

     ```
     sudo find /usr/local/ -iname *rhythmbox* -exec rm -rf {} \;
     ```
- **If there is only one copy**. Another assumption either some way you get rhythmbox itself that was build vs `libtotem-plparser.so.17` or one of the loaded plugins (any custom plugins?)

  1. Confirm `ldd /usr/bin/rhythmbox` list only `libtotem-plparser.so.18` (no `libtotem-plparser.so.17`)
  2. Then it could be a loaded plugin. Use `strace` for debuging:

     ```
     strace -e trace=open -o trace.log rhythmbox
     ```

     Check for paths which plugins are loaded from:

     ```
     grep -i plugin trace.log | sort
     grep -i "\.so" trace.log | sort
     ```

     Purge it manually:

     ```
      sudo rm -rf /usr/lib/rhythmbox/plugins/ /usr/share/rhythmbox/plugins/ [...]
     ```
- Purge packages then Reinstall

  ```
       sudo apt-get --purge remove -s 'rhythmbox*'
       sudo apt-get install rhythmbox
  ```

Comment: This might make the problem go away, but unfortunately doesn't help with knowing _why_ the problem is happening in the first place.

Comment: @dobey, yep (even if it works, still just a workaround) .

Comment: This allows me to start rhythmbox. However there are a number of fatal errors displayed in terminal when it loads. I'll paste them as a new update to the original question.

Comment: Added more information to the original question

Comment: Ahh! the result of `sudo updatedb; locate -r /bin/rhythmbox$` displays 2 entries 1) `/usr/bin/rhythmbox` and 2) `/usr/local/bin/rhythmbox` how do I remove them both so that I can just get version 3.0.3 rather than as I currently have version 2.99?!?!

Comment: @SimplySimon, I've add cleanup command. If rhythmbox was playing ok those are not fatal errors, most GTK apps have bunch warning messages but tool still works perfectly. ( If you want to try, after cleanup, run `rhythmbox` or `/usr/bin/rhythmbox` which is the last update, gonna see similar messages)

Answer (score 1):

You have an old build of rhythmbox installed into the `/usr/local` prefix. You should remove it from there. The following commands should help with that:

```
rm /usr/local/bin/rhythmbox*
rm /usr/local/lib/librhythmbox*
rm -rf /usr/local/lib/rhythmbox
rm -rf /usr/local/share/rhythmbox
rm /usr/local/share/applications/rhythmbox*
rm /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gnome.rhythmbox.gschema.xml
```

Then purge and re-install the version from the archive:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge librhythbmox-core8 libtotem-plparser17
sudo apt-get install rhythmbox
```

This should get you back to what is in the archive and a working rhythmbox.

Comment: Did that and it has stopped working again! `(rhythmbox:3265): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_css_provider_load_from_path: assertion 'path != NULL' failed`

Comment: ... `(rhythmbox:3701): GLib-GIO-ERROR **: Settings schema 'org.gnome.rhythmbox' does not contain a key named 'follow-playing'
Trace/breakpoint trap`

Comment: @SimplySimon - now that you've deleted the local rhythmbox install - try purging rhythmbox and reinstalling i.e. `sudo apt-get purge rhythmbox && sudo apt-get install --reinstall rhythmbox rhythmbox-plugins`

Comment: I've updated the answer with an additional rm command, and the commands to purge the existing install, and reinstall the archive version again.

Answer (score 0):

An educated guess tells that you may need to install the `libtotem-plparser18` package by opening a terminal and typing:

```
sudo apt-get install libtotem-plparser18
```

---

**How do you know that?**

I am able to open rhythmbox without that error message which would mean that I do have that package. So, open a terminal and type:

```
locate libtotem | grep plparser
```

which returned the following results:

```
/usr/lib/libtotem-plparser-mini.so.18
/usr/lib/libtotem-plparser-mini.so.18.1.0
/usr/lib/libtotem-plparser.so.18
/usr/lib/libtotem-plparser.so.18.1.0
/usr/share/doc/libtotem-plparser18
/usr/share/doc/libtotem-plparser18/AUTHORS
/usr/share/doc/libtotem-plparser18/NEWS.gz
/usr/share/doc/libtotem-plparser18/README
/usr/share/doc/libtotem-plparser18/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/libtotem-plparser18/copyright
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libtotem-plparser18.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libtotem-plparser18.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libtotem-plparser18.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libtotem-plparser18.postrm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libtotem-plparser18.shlibs
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libtotem-plparser18.symbols
```

out of which `/usr/lib/libtotem-plparser.so.18` "looks like" the best candidate. Now to get this shared object, you need to install it, so type:

```
apt-cache search libtotem-plparser
```

which returns:

```
libtotem-plparser-dbg - Totem Playlist Parser library - debugging symbols
libtotem-plparser-dev - Totem Playlist Parser library - development files
libtotem-plparser18 - Totem Playlist Parser library - runtime files
```

among which again `libtotem-plparser18` "looks like" the required package.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libtotem-plparser18` tells me that I already have the latest version installed.

Comment: I have also been through the rest of your answer and unfortunately, end up with the same error as supplied in the original question

Comment: @SimplySimon: What is the output of `ls -l /usr/lib/libtotem-plparser.so.18`?

Comment: lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 27 Apr  1 14:32 /usr/lib/libtotem-plparser.so.18 -> libtotem-plparser.so.18.1.0

Answer (score -1):

Since you've checked and the concerned .so file is present on the system, it means there's a linker problem.

Check out the solution given here:

[missing-a-shared-library-that-is-present-on-the-system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/45393/why-libreoffice-3-4-rc-1-missing-a-shared-library-that-is-present-on-the-system)

Of cource, instead of `locate libjvmfwk`, you'll use `locate libtotem-plparser`

Just for reference, I get the below result on my 14.04 64-bit:

`/usr/lib/libtotem-plparser-mini.so.17
/usr/lib/libtotem-plparser-mini.so.17.0.4
/usr/lib/libtotem-plparser-mini.so.18
/usr/lib/libtotem-plparser-mini.so.18.1.0
/usr/lib/libtotem-plparser.so.17
/usr/lib/libtotem-plparser.so.17.0.4
/usr/lib/libtotem-plparser.so.18
/usr/lib/libtotem-plparser.so.18.1.0`

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is what I get as well, with a few extra file types :)

Comment: So were you able to follow the steps given in the link I shared? What were the results?